# pub use / "export" many submodules at once

Tags: rust, macros, export, macro-rules

I need to define many types in one file (->submodule) each and expose them all on the same level of the module. This creates lots of repetitive overhead in the mod.rs:

```rust
mod foo;
mod bar;
mod baz;
[...]

pub use self::foo::*;
pub use self::bar::*;
pub use self::baz::*;
[...]
```

I tried to fix this with a macro, but it does not compile:

```rust
macro_rules! expose_submodules {
    ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => {
        $(
            mod $x;
            pub use self::$x::*;
        )*
    };
}
```

yields

```
error: expected identifier, found `foo`
 --> src/mod.rs:4:17
  |
4 |             mod $x;
  |                 ^^ expected identifier
  |
 ::: src/mod.rs:10:1
  |
2 | expose_submodules![foo, bar, baz];
  | ----------------------------------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `expose_submodules` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

(same issue when passing the parameters as strings).

How would I best fix this macro *or* do the whole task in more idiomatic rust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the macro you need to use `ident` fragment instead of `expr`:

```rust
macro_rules! expose_submodules {
    ( $( $x:ident ),* ) => {
        $(
            mod $x;
            pub use self::$x::*;
        )*
    };
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Do you know whether it is possible to further shorten the code by calling this macro for all submodule files in the same folder?

Comment: @philhob I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: All "foo", "bar" and "baz" submodules are in the same folder, each in their own file. So there are `mod.rs`, `foo.rs`, ... Is it possible to automatically call the macro (which I call from `mod.rs`) for all modules in the folder, that is all file names minus the `.rs` extension?

Comment: @philhob No, it is not possible.

Comment: Well it is possible with procedual macros, but not with declarative ones.

Comment: @cafce25 I don't think it is possible with procedural macros either, at least not without nightly APIs.